# Google Map in flutter not showing markers

Tags: android, flutter, google-maps, dart

I am trying to implete the Google Maps  Marker Functionality for my app. By using the Co-ordinates.

It works fine. But the markers/pointers not  shown in the map. only empty map is render on full screen

Any ways to Solve this issue ??

### Full Code

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class GoogleMapScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const GoogleMapScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _GoogleMapScreenState createState() => _GoogleMapScreenState();
}

class _GoogleMapScreenState extends State<GoogleMapScreen> {
  late GoogleMapController mapController;
  Set<Marker> markers = {};

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  void onMapcreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    setState(() {
      markers.add(const Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId('1'),
        position: LatLng(13.007488, 77.598656),
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(
          title: 'Marker Title Second ',
          snippet: 'My Custom Subtitle',
        ),
      ));
      markers.add(const Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId('2'),
        position: LatLng(12.999595, 77.585856),
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(
          title: 'Marker Title Third ',
          snippet: 'My Custom Subtitle',
        ),
      ));
      markers.add(const Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId('3'),
        position: LatLng(13.001916, 77.588849),
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(
          title: 'Marker Title Fourth ',
          snippet: 'My Custom Subtitle',
        ),
      ));
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBody: true,
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      body: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: GoogleMap(
          initialCameraPosition: const CameraPosition(
            target: LatLng(36.736847, 4.045026),
            zoom: 15,
          ),
          mapToolbarEnabled: true,
          buildingsEnabled: false,
          myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
          mapType: MapType.normal,
          markers: markers,
          onMapCreated: onMapcreated,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### Output

[image]

I used the Empty API key for Google API.

And also I need to hide the plus, minus symbol & copyrights from the map

Comment: can you try adding bitmap images to the markers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You need to have **Google Map API** Key Otherwise you'll see an empty white screen.

I tried your code only machine with google api key and it's working fine.
here is the code I've used(try to copy paste and check)

2.for hiding zoom button use `zoomControlsEnabled: true,`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class GoogleMapScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const GoogleMapScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _GoogleMapScreenState createState() => _GoogleMapScreenState();
}

class _GoogleMapScreenState extends State<GoogleMapScreen> {
  late GoogleMapController mapController;
  Set<Marker> markers = {};

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  void onMapcreated(GoogleMapController controller) {
    setState(() {
      markers.add(const Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId('1'),
        position: LatLng(13.007488, 77.598656),
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(
          title: 'Marker Title Second ',
          snippet: 'My Custom Subtitle',
        ),
      ));
      markers.add(const Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId('2'),
        position: LatLng(13.007481, 77.598651),
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(
          title: 'Marker Title Third ',
          snippet: 'My Custom Subtitle',
        ),
      ));
      markers.add(const Marker(
        markerId: MarkerId('3'),
        position: LatLng(13.001916, 77.588849),
        infoWindow: InfoWindow(
          title: 'Marker Title Fourth ',
          snippet: 'My Custom Subtitle',
        ),
      ));
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBody: true,
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      body: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        child: GoogleMap(
          initialCameraPosition: const CameraPosition(
            target: LatLng(13.007481, 77.598656),
            zoom: 10,
          ),
          mapToolbarEnabled: true,
          buildingsEnabled: false,
          myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
          mapType: MapType.normal,
          markers: markers,
          onMapCreated: onMapcreated,
          zoomControlsEnabled: true,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Note:**
I guess the problem was that your **target LatLng** was referring to the
different location and another reason could be that you didn’t
provided API key.

your earlier targer was `36.736847, 4.045026` to which i changed to `13.007488, 77.598656` nearest to your marker, including your zoom value from 15 to 10